# Haskell filter/split list

Tags: list, haskell

I want something like

```
splitBy pred list = ( filter pred list, filter (not . pred) list )
```

but in one pass.

Comment: Hoogle is your friend.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking for the [`partition`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base//Data-List.html#v%3apartition) function from `Data.List`:

```
partition :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

It can be implemented nicely using a fold:

```
splitBy pred = foldr f ([], []) 
    where f x ~(yes, no) = if pred x then (x : yes, no) 
                                    else (yes, x : no)
```

Comment: That should be `f x ~(yes,no) = if ...`, or it won't work at all on infinite lists, and be inefficient for long finite lists.

Comment: @Daniel: I've never seen that syntax, what does it mean? Non-strict tuple?

Comment: It's a lazy pattern. For a refutable pattern `pat` (like `(x,y)` is), `~pat` makes the pattern irrefutable, i.e. the argument is bound to the pattern without inspecting it (and the components to the corresponding sub-patterns) - and when the argument passed does in fact not match the pattern, you get a pattern match failure at runtime. For `partition`, with a strict pattern, the fold would have to traverse the entire list to see that the second argument indeed matches, and then build the pair of lists traversing backwards. With a lazy pattern, it can start building immediately.

Comment: That makes it equivalent to `f x pair = if pred x then (x:fst pair, snd pair) else (fst pair, x:snd pair)`, just nicer.